# Retrieve the duplicate data without group from subquery

Tags: mysql

i have tables below

catalog_product_entity

| entity_id | sku | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-1669197697 | bundle |
| 2 | skua | single |
| 3 | skub | single |
| 4 | skuc | single |

catalog_product_bundle_selection

| parent_product_id | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |

promotion

| sku |
| --- |
| 1-1669197697 |

product_shipping

| product_id | code |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | jne |
| 2 | jnt |
| 3 | jne |
| 3 | jnt |
| 4 | jne |
| 4 | jnt |

and the sample queries

```sql
SELECT e.*, COUNT(DISTINCT bundle.product_id) AS children FROM catalog_product_entity AS e
INNER JOIN product_promotion AS promotion ON promotion.sku = e.sku
INNER JOIN catalog_product_bundle_selection AS bundle ON bundle.parent_product_id = e.entity_id
INNER JOIN product_shipping AS shipping ON shipping.product_id = bundle.product_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT bundle.product_id) AS total_item, product.sku
    FROM catalog_product_bundle_selection AS bundle
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity AS product ON product.entity_id = bundle.parent_product_id
    INNER JOIN product_promotion AS promotion ON promotion.sku = product.sku
    GROUP BY product.sku
) AS summary ON summary.sku = e.sku
GROUP BY e.entity_id, shipping.code, summary.total_item
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT bundle.product_id) = summary.total_item
```

and the result is

[image]

There is a bundle with 3 items that have different shipping, but same as the others. The point is i want to get the data bundle with condition if the items have at least one or more similar shipping.

how can i retrieve only one record without put the above query inside subquery and group it by parent, anyone can help?

Comment: Does the inlined data actually exist in one or more tables?

Comment: Yes it does. The above is just an example

Comment: Please edit your question and replace the union queries with table names.  Then add the data as sample table data instead.

Comment: @Nugraha.A Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.